# SQL Query to append data to column with array field?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose I have a table

```
no                       id
integer                  integer[]

7                          {9,2,3}
97                         {2,14,4}
29                          {2,5,7}
4                           {1,2,3,4}
```

Now I want to add the elements {5,6} to the array id where no=4.
If I use the update statement, the previous contents(1,2,3,4) are being erased and {5,6} is stored. But I want to append {5,6} to {1,2,3,4}.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I am using "postgres"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [concatenation operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html) `||`

```
update the_table
   set id = id || array[5,6]
where id = 4;
```